# problem with alpha and lambda regularization parameters in python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Question : 
 Logistic Regression Train logistic regression models with L1 regularization and L2 regularization using alpha = 0.1
and lambda = 0.1. Report accuracy, precision, recall, f1-score and print the confusion matrix

My code  is :

```
_lambda = 0.1
c = 1/_lambda
classifier = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1',C=c)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

I don't know where is really location of alpha and lambda.
Did I work right?

Comment: You can `print(classifier.C)` to retrieve the value of `1/_lambda` that was used to train the model. That is the regularization parameter. There is no other `alpha` setting here. The `alpha` setting for regularization is only used in `SGDClassifier`

Comment: you can't put l1 and l2 normalization parameters at the same time. it's one or the other, else you have to do an elatic net regularization and then it's SGDClassifier(
implements logistic regression with elastic net penalty (SGDClassifier(loss="log", penalty="elasticnet")))

Comment: Hey @Alexis , is SGDClassifier Have Lambda and Alpha parameter together?

Comment: yes it use them both. from doc: The regularizer is a penalty added to the loss function that shrinks model parameters towards the zero vector using either the squared euclidean norm L2 or the absolute norm L1 or a combination of both (Elastic Net). try to use it but read a lot before doing so. As mention in answers, if you don't understand well what you are doing you won't achieve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### your example

alpha=0, lambda=10 (AKA .1/1)

#### alpha

alpha is the parameter that adds penalty for number of features to control overfitting, in this case either L1 (Lasso Regression) or L2 (Ridge Regression). L1 and L2 penalty cannot both be done at the same time, as there is only one Lambda coefficient. Quick aside - Elastic Net is an alpha parameter that is somewhere in between L1 and L2, so for example, if you are using sklearn.SGD_Regressor() alpha=0 is L1 alpha=0.5 is elasticnet, alpha=1 is Ridge.

#### Lambda

is a term that controls the learning rate. In other words, how much change do you want the model to make during each iteration of learning.

#### confusion

To make matters worse, these terms are often used interchangedly, I think due to different yet similar concepts in graph theory, statistical theory, mathematical theory, and the individuals who write commonly-used machine-learning libraries

check out some info here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-ridge-lasso-regression-python/ but also look for some of the free academic textbooks about statistical learning.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I need both alpha and lambda altogether. it it possible?Any way?

Comment: the first line of my post tells you the values of alpha and lambda that you used. if you want lambda = .1. then just set C=0.1

Comment: Thanks. I want to change alpha in code simultaneously, is it posible?

Comment: not with sklearn LogisticRegression, as @Alexis mentioned above, you can specify this parameter in SGDClassifier(loss='log'). However, take some time to read through the linked source, watch some videos etc.. It is crucial that you understand the meaning behind these terms, if you want to use machine-learning in the real world.